# Creating a new column/vector of expressions in R

Tags: r, purrr, rlang, plotmath

I have an example dataset:

```
test <- data.frame(x = c("BG10", "C1456", "DXT6"), y = c("293S", "124F", "124F"))
      x    y
1  BG10 293S
2 C1456 124F
3  DXT6 124F
```

where I am ultimately trying to combine columns `x` and `y`, and then label the new column such that values in `x` are on top of `y` for plotting purposes:

```
test %>% mutate(label = paste(x, y, sep = " "), labels = factor(label, labels = bquote(atop(.(x), .(y)))))
```

the above will give an error.

I thought of creating a vector of expressions:

```
test %>% split(.$x) %>% map(~ bquote(atop(.(.$x), .(.$y)))) %>% unlist(use.names = FALSE)
[[1]]
atop("BG10", "293S")

[[2]]
atop("C1456", "124F")

[[3]]
atop("DXT6", "124F")
```

But it would remove the expressions whenever I tried converting the list to a vector. Are there any suggestions on how to go about this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can `Map` them into a list-column of expressions.

```r
library(dplyr) # not strictly required ...
out <- test %>%
  mutate(label = Map(function(a, b) bquote(atop(.(a), .(b))), x, y))
out
#       x    y                 label
# 1  BG10 293S  atop("BG10", "293S")
# 2 C1456 124F atop("C1456", "124F")
# 3  DXT6 124F  atop("DXT6", "124F")
```

We can verify they are expressions ("language") with `str`:

```r
str(out)
# 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ x    : chr  "BG10" "C1456" "DXT6"
#  $ y    : chr  "293S" "124F" "124F"
#  $ label:List of 3
#   ..$ BG10 : language atop("BG10", "293S")
#   ..$ C1456: language atop("C1456", "124F")
#   ..$ DXT6 : language atop("DXT6", "124F")
```

and verify that other tools will treat them as such:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(out, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = label), parse = TRUE)
```

[image: sample ggplot with quoted "atop" text labels]

(If you prefer to use `purrr`, then replace the `Map` with

```r
pmap(list(x, y), ~ bquote(atop(.(.x), .(.y))))
```

Answer (score 4):

A simple alternative is to just `paste` the strings together with a newline character:

```r
test$label <- paste(test$x, test$y, sep = '\n')
```

Giving you

```r
ggplot(test, aes(x, y, label = label)) + geom_text()
```

[image]

Comment: Simple. I thought about going this route too, but wondered if `atop(..)` was really a placeholder for more `plotmath` expressions that may not be resolved as quickly with an embedded newline. Nice though!

Comment: @r2evans I thought from the OP that this was the ultimate goal. However, the green tick suggests you were indeed closer to the mark, and your answer is certainly more generally useful.

Comment: Or it could have been that my answer accrued one more up-vote at the time of acceptance, and peer-pressure led them to accept mine instead. Shrug. Interpretation of social norms is a funny thing.

Comment: I appreciate both answers! My actual data + plot requires more plotmath expressions, which is why I kept the `atop` placeholder. Thank you both!